# How to customize YouTube Player style MINIMAL to hide seek bar and enable play/pause control in android

Tags: android, youtube, seekbar, mediacontroller

I am using YouTube API in my android application. I need to disable some controls of the YouTube player. So that i used YouTubePlayer.PlayerStyle enum class.

*youTubePlayer.setPlayerStyle(YouTubePlayer.PlayerStyle.MINIMAL);*

But in this case, A minimal style, showing a time(seek) bar and play/pause controls. I have to enable only play/pause controls and i have to disable seek bar. How can i do that????

Comment: Change playstyle from MINIMAL to CHROMELESS. that is it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/67406221/13146544 please answer this if possible

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a direct way to do this.
You can set the playstyle to MINIMAL(this keeps the play/pause button) and add your own custom seek bar using a SeekBar view.

You can see a sample code for it [here](https://stacktips.com/tutorials/android/how-to-customize-youtubeplayer-controls-in-android).

Comment: But how will I add the custom seekbar in full screen mode?